# c++ How to put path from command line argument to fprintf

Tags: c++, file, path, format, printf

I am having trouble figuring out how to take a path from the command line argument and having my program write to that folder using fprinf. For example: /here would write the file to the "here" folder with /here being the path from where the program is to where it needs to be written. Same for if the path were /there/here. This is just this section of my code:

```
    void write_file(int sockfd, char* path)
    {
       int n;
       FILE *fp;
       char filename[] = "file1.txt";
       char buffer[SIZE];

       fp = fopen(filename, "w");
       if (fp == NULL)
       {
          std::cerr << "ERROR: Could not write file.\n";
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
       while (1)
       {
          n = recv(sockfd, buffer, SIZE, 0);
          if (n <= 0)
          {
             break;
             return;
          }
          fprintf(fp, "%s", buffer);
          bzero(buffer, SIZE);
       }
       fclose(fp);
       return;
    }
```

This code works but saves the file in my current folder. The variable "path" is the command line argument.

Edit: This is code that does not print lines to a file. Instead it copies lines from an existing file and puts those lines into the "file1.txt" file.

Comment: Do you know about *`snprintf`*? You can use it to construct strings containing multiple values, likes two other strings formatted as `%s/%s`.

Comment: Also, `fprintf(fp, "%s", buffer);` is kind of dangerous... Are you *sure* that the contents in `buffer` will be a *null-terminated* string?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how would I use snprintf since it does not accept the open file as an argument

Comment: Does anyone understands the question? I do not think problem is use of `frprintf`, but understanding difference path/directory of: executable, running location and impact of absolute relative paths.

Comment: And most probably missing terminating zero is a problem.

Comment: @Capsaisyn please edit your question and explain your problem clearly. Your problem description doesn't seem to have anything in common with code provided (the only thing which is related is `fp = fopen(filename, "w");`)

Comment: @MarekR the problem was stated in the first line. I need to save the file into whatever folder is stated in the command-line argument. This code saves it to the same folder that the code is located. So, if I type /here into the command line, I want it to go into the 'here' folder and save it there.

Comment: You use `snprintf` (to continue with the C-like code) to create the full path, using `path` and `filename`, and then use the full path in the call to `fopen`. But considering that you've tagged this C++ you should really be using [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) (C++17):

```
void write_file(int sockfd, const char* path)
{
    auto filename = std::filesystem::path(path) / "file1.txt";
    std::ofstream out{ filename, ios::trunc | ios::out };
    if (!out) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << std::strerror(errno) << "\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char buffer[SIZE];
    while (1)
    {
        int n = recv(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (n == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (n < 0) {
            std::cerr << "ERROR: " << std::strerror(errno) << "\n";
            break;
        }
        if (!out.write(buffer, n)) {
            std::cerr << "ERROR: " << std::strerror(errno) << "\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't have `std::filesystem` support, you can replace the first 2 statements with some manual path concatenation like:

```
    std::string filename = path;
    if (filename != "" && filename.back() != '/')
        filename += '/';
    filename += "file1.txt";
```

Comment: I got it to work using the  non std::filesystem version. Thank you so much!

Comment: It turns out that my FILE* fp was transferring the file perfect to our eyes, but was changing things behind the scene. So, I had to change it to using ofstream and your code really helped me figure out how to use it and purpose it to what I need. Thank you so much!